# SQL Report Builder - Referencing Group On value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

New to Report Builder so not sure if this is possible or not but when creating groups, is there a way to reference the value of the group itself in an expression?

Lets say for example I've got the following

```
Type    Amount
=====   ======
A       $200.00
A       $100.00
B       $100.00
B       $50.00
C       $75.00
C       $25.00
```

So now I create a group, TypeGroup that groups on the 'Type' field, however when aggregating 'Amount', depending on what the 'Type' is determines the aggregation.  So if TypeGroup = A, get the max of amount, if it's B get the avg, if it's C get the Sum.  So in the Tablix body, I need to somehow reference which group that cell belongs to in an expression.

Something like this.

```
=iif(Group!TypeGroup = "A", Max(Field!Amount.Value),iif(Group!TypeGroup = "B", AVG(Fields!Amount.Value),SUM(Fields!Amount.Value)
```

It's the syntax for 'Group!TypeGroup' that I'm not sure on (if such a thing even existing)

This is a simple example to try and describe what I'm looking for, my situation is a lot more complex.  I have a long way workaround for what I need, I was just hoping that there was a way to reference the group to simplify things for me.

Thx for any answers.

Comment: Why do you need to get a "group type"?   If the group is on type, won't all the individual members of the group have the same type?   So couldn't you just get the type of the current member?

Comment: If it was as simple as this example, correct, however the expression I'm using to Group On uses nested iif's and date ranges and references additional fields.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could do this inside your query instead? It seems to me like this could be easier in a SQL Query.

Comment: The actual expression that I'm using to Group On uses nested iif's and date ranges and references additional fields.  Adding all of this into the query itself is one option that I've been toying with, I was just hoping for an easier solution before I head that route.